# Schedule Refresh Web URL in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I get the data from web URL json file  in PowerBI but the issue is when I apply scheduled refresh it is shown an error  Attached is the screenshot of error I used gateway with Anonymous. plz let me know how to resolve this error.  [image]

[image]

Comment: The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Can you access this source outside of powerbi

Comment: now the error has changed "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation" I already mentioned Timeout limit which is 5 in advanced editor PowerBI Desktop but I don't know why this error occurs?